# SED: Combine text between two pattern in same line

Tags: sed, awk

I m trying to use sed /awk command to parse my text file.
I want to print text between two pattern in same line with some character added in it.
ex: 
If my line is

`uint8_t aucRepresentationName[NR_UNIT_REPRESENTATIONS][CHARS_P_REPRESENTATION];`

OR

```
uint8_t aucRepresentationName [NR_UNIT_REPRESENTATIONS] [CHARS_P_REPRESENTATION];
```

I want to print `NR_UNIT_REPRESENTATIONS*CHARS_P_REPRESENTATION`

So , I have stared with sed command to insert line deliminter `\n` after `'['` , deviding line in suitable species and then tried to parse it again.

```
echo "bla bla bla [AK] bla bla bla bla [A_K] bla bla bla" | sed 's/\[/\n&/g;' | awk '{sub(/.*\[ /,"");sub(/\].*/,"");print;}'

echo "bla bla bla [AK] bla bla bla bla [A_K] bla bla bla" | sed 's/\[/\n&/g;' | sed -e 's/^.*\[ //g;s/ \].*$//g'
```

And  it is not always two diamensional array, it could be none  or single/double dimentional array, I need to first how many instance of [], if its 0 then write 1, if its single diamensional array then ex A[SIZE] then write SIZE its two diamensional array ex:A[RAW][COL] write RAW*COL..

I would like to know what is wrong in my command? or any other option to do it as it will help me to further study sed.

Amruta

Comment: There is no tool named sed/awk. sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line. For all other text manipulation you should use awk. You do not need to study sed - you can pick up everything you need to know about it from a couple of examples.  Study awk by reading the book "Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition" to start.

Comment: What does a no-dimensional array look like in your code? Is it an array with size [] or is it a scalar variable or something else? Post some more representative sample input that includes all flavors of array declaration you want to parse and the expected output given that input.

Comment: My text file contains scalar variables, and some array. Say U8 A, U16 B[5], U16 B[4][2], u32 C[2][3][4].. and so on.. And I need to parse this file and store result in file as..   U8 1 U16 5 U16 4*2 U32 2*3*4

Comment: You should update your question to show representative sample input and expected output rather than try to describe it to us in a comment so we have to figure out sample input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
awk -F '[][]' '{print $2,$4}' OFS=\* file
```

---

OK, if it is a single occurrence of 0,1 or two-dimensional in one page you could try:

```
awk -F '[][]' '{if(NF==3)print $2; else if(NF>4)print $2,$4; else print 1}' OFS=\* file
```

or less comprehensible ;) :

```
awk -F '[][]' '{$0=NF==3?$2:NF>4?$2 OFS $4:1}1' OFS=\* file
```

Comment: But it is not always two diamensional array, it could be none or single/double dimentional array, I need to first how many instance of [], if its 0 then do write 1, if its single diamensional array then ex A[SIZE] then write SIZE its two diamensional array ex:A[RAW][COL] write RAW*COL..

Comment: Hi, I was trying to use command you have mentioned above.Command is echo $Readline | awk -F '[][]' '{$0=NF==3?$2:NF>4?$2 OFS $4:1}1' OFS=\* where readline contains line read from text file. Surprisingly it works on prompt but not when I was executing it from my .sh file. it always print "1" I could not find reason

Comment: Difficult to say why there is a difference. Could you provide a sample input file and script detail and provide details, like OS, shell and versions?

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
perl -lne 'push @a,/\[([^\]]*)\]/g;END{print join "*",@a}'
```

modified from [here](http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/01/capturing-all-regex-matches-into-array.html)
tested below:

```
> echo "bla [AK] bla [A_K] 10" | perl -lne 'push @a,/\[([^\]]*)\]/g;END{print join "*",@a}'
AK*A_K
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
echo "bla bla bla [AK] bla bla bla bla [A_K] bla bla bla" | sed 's/.*\[\(.*\)\].*\[\(.*\)\].*/\1*\2/g'
```

> AK*A_K

Comment: But it is not always two diamensional array, it could be none  or single/double dimentional array, I need to first how many instance of [], if its 0 then do write 1, if its single diamensional array then ex A[SIZE] then write SIZE its two diamensional array ex:A[RAW][COL] write RAW*COL..

Answer (score 0):

With sed:

```
sed -n 's/[^]]*\[\([^]]*\)\]\s*\[\([^]]*\)\].*$/\1*\2/p' input
```